# ionic framework: conditional animation depending on the os

Tags: android, angularjs, animation, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to disable animations in Ionic Framework for Android OS. I have tried:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" animation="{'no-animation': ionic.Platform.is('android')}">
```

This doesn't work. When I change **animation** to **ng-animation**, it adds the class "no-animation" to navbar but doesn't disable the animation. Is there any way I can target specific OSes in Ionic Framework?

Answer (score 1):

Check out Ionic.Platform: http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/utility/ionic.Platform/ Also, the Device plugin in general for Cordova could help.

Answer (score 0):

I used some vanilla javascript to add the attribute which worked. Although I am not so sure if it is the proper way to do. Here is the code added to index.html file:

```
    <script>
        var noAnimation = ionic.Platform.is('android'),
        body = document.getElementById("bd"),
        navbar = document.getElementById("nb");

        if(noAnimation) {
            body.setAttribute('animation', 'no-animation');
            navbar.setAttribute('animation', 'no-animation');
        }
    </script>
```